# WinRT8.1 Toast Notifications not working in Windows 10 Device

Tags: winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10, toast

I have an Existing WinRT 8.1 App. All Toast Notifications works beautifully on Win8.1 OS.

Now when I tried to run the same 8.1 app on Win10 OS, I don’t see any notifications. Do I need to do something extra?

**Note**: Action center is enabled and I have not restricted any App specific notifications in notification Center.

*(Also raised this question in one of the MSDN blogs. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/07/08/quickstart-sending-a-local-toast-notification-and-handling-activations-from-it-windows-10/#comment-2862)*

Comment: Could you share [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Questions *seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")* must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Besides, have you tested your app in other Windows 10 devices? Do they also not work?

Comment: Below is the Minimum code which added to Win8.1 app doesn't work with Win10 OS and when added to UWP app works with Win10 OS.


var toastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
    var toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText01);
    var toastText = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
            (toastText[0] as XmlElement).InnerText = "Line 1";
    var toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
            toastNotifier.Show(toast);

Comment: It has something to do with ToastCapable="true" property in Manifest file. Below are my observations....

1) First Time run ever with Toast Capable to true - No Toasts
2) Seconds time run without Toast capability - Displayed Toasts.
3) Third time run back with Toast Capable to true - Displayed Toasts.

->> Not sure why its behaving strange though.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue in my side. No matter how I set `ToastCapable` even when I set it to `false`, the toast always displays with Windows 10 OS. Actually, there is no more ToastCapable in Windows 10. All UWP apps are capable of sending toast notifications, without the need to declare any capability in the app’s manifest file anymore. My OS Build is 10586.218 Version 1511. You may create a new blank Windows 8.1 app and test with your code to see if the problem still there.

Comment: Yes I was able to get it work with even Toast Capable setting removed in Win8.1 Apps. I narrowed it down to Assigned Access. This happens to be with Associate Persona when few settings are locked down. With Admin Persona and all settings are enabled I don't see the issue.